# Ubuntu's gui "Open With" command is not memorizing the application

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, nautilus

In Ubuntu, when we right-click a icon and use "open with", there is an option to remember that application for that file's type.

For some reason, my system is no more memorizing the application (I think it was aftare some update).

And, even when I have already used the "open with" command, the application is not showing in the "open with" list, so I have, everytime, to go to "open with"->"Other Application".

The system used to ask me what to do with the file type (Display, Run..), but now it is doing nothing to my file type "ppf". I want it to open with GEdit. Is there any command line to associate my extension with GEdit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found, after unmark "Allow executing file as a program" it worked.. I don't know why this box was marked anyway..

Answer (score 3):

Right-click the document icon in nautilus, then choose `Properties` | `Open With`. This will allow you to choose the default application to launch it with, as well as modify the applications that show by default in the context menu of documents of that type.

Comment: it is already marked GEdit, but when I click (or press enter) it just don't react... nothing happens. And I think this started after one of the Ubuntu updates, but I don't know what was updated... any other idea?

Comment: found, after unmark "Allow executing file as a program" it worked.. I don't know why this box was marked anyway..

Answer (score 2):

Mine never did remember settings when set via the Nautilus "open with" dialog.  (I was trying to make VLC my default player for various video filetypes -- AVI, etc -- and it never stuck.)

I eventually got the setting to stick using Ubuntu Tweak's File Type Manager.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa

sudo aptitude update

sudo aptitude install ubuntu-tweak
```

Afterwards, Ubuntu Tweak should be available in your Gnome menu: *Applications > System Tools > Ubuntu Tweak*.  Select *File Type Manager* in the left-hand column, select a filetype category, select a filetype, click the *Edit* button.  There you can select from your system's known choices, or use *Add* to add a new choice or custom command.

---

See [Adding MIME Types](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AddingMimeTypes) in the Ubuntu Help pages.  To make a new MIME type, you can simply add the type to */etc/mime.types* and the icon to /usr/share/icons/gnome/*/mimetypes (put SVGs in ...gnome/scalable/mimetypes, and PNGs in the size directories).

There seems to be a way to make this slightly more automatic via XDG.  You can use the *xdg-mime* command to query what your system knows about MIME types and add new ones.  See [*man xdg-mime*](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man1/xdg-mime.1.html); install the *xdg-utils* package if you don't have this command.

If your PPF files are just plain text, you might be able to get away with adding "ppf" to the existing *text/plain* definition in */etc/mime.types*:

```
text/plain                  asc txt text pot brf ppf
```

Comment: An error has occurred:
Error reading https://launchpad.net/api/1.0/~tualatrix/+archive/paa: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

Comment: The above error occurred on the first line

Comment: @Tom: watch out for typos; that should be `ppa` on the end not `paa`: https://launchpad.net/api/1.0/~tualatrix/+archive/ppa .. in case it's not obvious, your system will need an internet connection to run those commands.  i've just double-checked; these commands are working on my system.

Comment: Thanks! But, now installed, there are just options to edit known file types, even when unmarking "Only show filetypes with associated applications". I need to register a new file type, "ppf", to open with gedit, is there a way?

Comment: @tom: sorry, i'm a little lost there myself.  ... hang on, updating the answer here.

Comment: no news here, what about you? The Ignacio answer didn't work here either, something is bugged here..

Comment: @Tom: did you look into the stuff i added?  either changing */etc/mime.types* or reading up on *xdg-mime*?  what did you try that didn't work?

Comment: found, after unmark "Allow executing file as a program" it worked.. I don't know why this box was marked anyway.. XD

Answer (score 1):

I was having this trouble until I noticed that my boot partition was full and cleared some space.
It was interesting - I released a few tens of megabytes and that freed up the system enough to work and then it somehow released more than a gigabyte on that partition that it was holding for some reason or another.
Whew.