# make quantaplus a default editor for php files in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, nautilus

In Ubuntu, how can I make Quanta Plus the default editor for PHP files?

In Windows we just use the *open with* context menu the first time for any new types of files and check ***use this application for these type of files***.  After that the files always open up in checked application.  I want to know if Ubuntu has a similar feature.

Also, if I open 2 PHP files then two instance of Quanta Plus opens up.  How can I get the secondary PHP files to open on another tab instead?

Comment: see my answer on [this related question](http://superuser.com/questions/152324/ubuntus-gui-open-with-command-is-not-memorizing-the-application) for alternatives to Nautilus' built-in "open with" feature.  (setting a default with Nautilus never works for me.)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `/etc/gnome/defaults.list` and look for `PHP` and change it with quantaplus and restart your X session.

If it doesn't have php entry, Try this.

- Right click on any PHP file and navigate to Open With tab.
- Add Quanta application using add button at the bottom
- After adding it , select it from option.

Comment: `PHP` not found in `/etc/gnome/defaults.list`, currently it's open in gedit by default

Comment: each time i have to select it through option? i want to escape from that sir

Comment: No, Not every time, just one time. After that file manager make that as a default one :)

Answer (score 0):

If you open a folder with a PHP file, then you can right click on the file and select "Open with other application ..." This will give you a dialog box where you can select the quantaplus editor. Make sure you tick the checkbox at the bottom of the dialog box which says 'Remember this application for "PHP script" files'.

Comment: @ Hamish there is no checkbox at bottom....

`Remember this application for "PHP script" files`